# _score while doing indexing in elasticsearch

Tags: php, elasticsearch

```
{
  "query": {
    "custom_score": {
      "query": {
        "match": {
          "xxx": {
            "query": "foobar"
          }
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "and": [
          {
            "query": {
              "match": {
                "yyyy": {
                  "query": "barfoo"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "script": "_score * doc['_score']"
  }
}
```

This gives error

```
 [custom_score] query does not support [filter]
```

Then how to evaluate such query?

Comment: Do you mean index time boosting? Could you elaborate a little bit more on what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Thanks, but I don't get it :) Can you explain what you are trying to achieve with your script? I think you should rephrase your question as it is not while indexing but more query time boosting. Also, if you look again at your exception you should find a more detailed message containing the reason why the query fails.

Comment: updated my question to clear it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to look at your requirements regarding boosting, since your current script doesn't make much sense.

Also, have a look at the documentation for the elasticsearch [query DSL](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/). It provides either compound queries and simple ones, which you can combine together. As the error says, you can't put a filter inside a custom score query. You can either use a [filtered query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/filtered-query/) inside the custom score query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "custom_score": {
      "query": {
        "filtered" : {
          "query" : {
            "match": {
              "xxx": {
                "query": "foobar"
              }
            }
          },
          "filter" : {
            "and": [
              {
                "query": {
                  "match": {
                    "yyyy": {
                      "query": "barfoo"
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      "script": "_score * doc['_score']"
    }
  }
}
```

or use a top level [filter](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/search/filter/) like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "custom_score": {
      "query": {
        "match": {
          "xxx": {
            "query": "foobar"
          }
        }
      },
      "script": "_score * doc['_score']"
    }
  },
  "filter": {
    "and": [
      {
        "query": {
          "match": {
            "yyyy": {
              "query": "barfoo"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The difference between the two options is that the top level filter is not considered if you make facets too in your search request, while if you put the filters within the query they are considered.

One other thing to look at: you don't need an and filter if you have only a single clause. Also, it usually doesn't make sense to put a full-text search within a filter, since filters are cacheable and given that full-text searches are free and pretty much unpredictable it would be a waste to cache them.

Comment: The "script" property should be within the parentheses of the "custom_score" property, not outside of it. Thanks for your various examples across SO, very helpful.