# Elasticsearch: how to make product name count more than product description in a search?

Tags: java, lucene, elasticsearch

I am building an e-commerce site. When searching for products with a string, I want to search the `name` field and the `description` field, and I want the name field to be more important than description.

How can I do this and what terminology should I look at?

Comment: [boost](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_boosting_query_clauses.html)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12427449/elasticsearch-boosting-relevance-based-on-field-value)

Answer (score 1):

This is an example concerning the `query_string` section in the query :

```
 "query_string" : {
    "fields" : ["description", "name^5"],
    "query" : "this AND that OR thus",
 }
```

You can read more about Query String [here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html)