# How do i add boosting to the elasticsearch mapping in ONGR?

Tags: elasticsearch, solr-boost, ongr

I want to boost documents in my ONGR setup. As show [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21366697) the most efficiant way to do so, is by adding it to the mapping:

```
"boosting_field": {"type" : "integer", "store" : "yes", "index" : "yes", "boost" : 10.0,}
```

How can i do that in ONGR?

Answer (score 1):

Boosting fields at index time in the mapping is [strongly discouraged](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-boost.html) because once set you can never change the boost of your field. Moreover this feature might even be removed in future versions.

So you should definitely go for query-time boosting, which is a much more flexible way to boost your fields.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add any custom field to the mapping in this particular case `boost`, you can do it via options, see the example below:

```
//...
    /**
     * @ES\Property(type="string", options={"boost"="10"})
     */
    public $title;
//...
```

Answer (score 0):

You definitely have to avoid using boost in the index mapping. Instead, in the search try to use field weights. e.g.

```
{
"query": {
"bool": {
  "should": [
    {
      "term": {
        "title": "acme^2"
      }
    },
    {
      "term": {
        "description": "bar^1"
      }
    }
   ]
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: But how if i want to have the boosting value in a special field?

Comment: I want to have a int field which contains a pre calculated boosting value that should influence the sorting (not overwrite it).

Comment: When you define a document field use options: @ES\Property(type="string", options={"boost"="10"})