# Elasticsearch : Use rank feature query as multiplier to the search relevance score

Tags: elasticsearch

**Disclaimer : I checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12427449/elasticsearch-boosting-relevance-based-on-field-value?rq=1) post for boosting relevance score but it was written a long time ago and does not cover the rank feature query.**

I want to boost relevance score of my documents based on a field present in the document itself.
Elasticsearch documentation mentions [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-rank-feature-query.html#rank-feature-query-logarithm) that the best way to do this is to use rank feature query which is optimized for this use case.

However, when I use this - I am only able to get the score from rank feature query to add to my search relevance score. And since I don't know the range of my search relevance score, I have no way of saying with confidence what impact my boost values will have on the overall score.

Is there any way to multiply the rank feature score with the search relevance score instead?